# insert duplicate rows in temp table

Tags: sql

i'm a new to sql & forum - need help on how to insert duplicate rows in temp table.  Would like to create a view as result

```
View - Employee:
Name  Empid  Status  Manager  Dept     StartDate  EndDate
AAA   111    Active  A111     Cashier  2015-01-01 2015-05-01
AAA   111    Active  A222      Sales    2015-05-01 NULL
```

I don't know how to write a function, but do have a DATE table.
Date Table: (365 days) goes up to 2018

```
Date          Fiscal_Wk       Fiscal_Mon       Fiscal_Yr
2015-01-01        1               1                2015
```

Result inquiry
How do i duplicate rows for each record from Employee base on each of the start date for entire calendar year.

```
Result: 
Name  Empid  Status  Manager  Dept      Date            FW    FM     FY
AAA   111    Active  A111     Cashier  2015-01-01        1     1    2015
AAA   111    Active  A111     Cashier  2015-01-02        1     1    2015
```

******so on!!!!!!

```
AAA   111    Active  A222      Sales   2015-05-01        18    5    2015
AAA   111    Active  A222      Sales   2015-05-02        18    5    2015
```

******so on!!!!!!

Thanks in advance,

Quinn

Comment: where is the code you tried?

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you are trying?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified query - this yields result of previous & most recent records

select e.*, c.date, c.FW, c.FM, c.FY
from employee e 
     join calendar c 
    on  e.startdate <= c.date and 
    ISNULL(e.enddate,GETDATE()) > c.date

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `join` operation.  However, the condition for the `join` is not equality, because you want all rows that match between two values.

The basic idea is:

```
select e.*, c.date
from employee e join
     calendar c
     on e.startdate >= c.date and
        (e.enddate is null or c.date <= e.enddate);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon - appreciate the response. I followed your query & it works great. Only thing is the result only shows records from the latest startdate with null enddate. Missing: 1) Previous records from prior startdate with existing enddate 2) Continue duplicates of records of last startdate with null end- let say to end of year.

Please help - it's been a nightmare - Thanks!

Comment: @Quinn . . . I had the end logic backwards.

Comment: sorry i'm not getting this

Comment: The code had `e.enddate <= c.date` rather than `c.date <= e.enddate`.

Comment: I tried this earlier after first response and result shows the same.  The result is missing 1 & 2 listed in last comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Employee cross join Calendar.
```

This will essentially join every record in calendar to every record in Employee.
so, if there are 2 records in Employee and 10 in calendar, you'll end up with 20 total, 10 for each.